# В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли как то определить место, на котором генерируется исключение?
В винформе определил функцию удаления, после нажатия на элементе и подтверждения удаления, выскакивает ошибка "В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект". Сравниваю с похожим проектом - все одинаково. Как найти ошибку?

Comment: Смотрите трассировку стека исключения, пользуйтесь точками останова (брейкпоинтами)

Answer (score 1):

`NullReferenceException` - это ошибка, которая возникает, когда вы обращаетесь к не инициализированному полю или переменной ссылочного типа.

Например:

```
List<Int32> list;
list.Add(10);
```

Вы можете воспользоваться отладчиком, чтобы найти проблему. [Включите остановку](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) при возникновении `NullReferenceException` и запустите выполнение в режиме отладки. После падения, наведите мышь на переменные в строке ошибки и найдите ту, что имеет значение `null`.

Отладчик Visual studio 2017 позволяет видеть имена полей и переменных, для которых вы потеряли ссылку.

[image: имя объекта с нулевым указателем]